# OutOfMemoryError metaspace in SBT 1.3.1

Tags: scala, sbt, out-of-memory, metaspace

I have a SBT project running on scala 2.11.12 and SBT 1.2.1 . I recently upgraded the SBT version to 1.3.1. Suddenly I started getting OOM error.

My SBT OPTS with SBT 1.2.1 are like this.

```
-J-Xms512M
-J-Xmx4G
-J-Xss2M
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Now when I change the XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to 3072M, I suddenly see OOM vanishing.

Is it a reasonable workaround to use more Metaspace just for a newer SBT version ?

Comment: Sbt 1.3 is already quite old, did you try with SBT 1.5 out of curiosity?

Comment: Also when does the OOM appears? Running a specific SBT task?